# Cant download andrioid emulator in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying to learn Xamarin but I cant seem to install Android emulator (not talking about the standalone version) Visual studio. I keep on getting the errors:

[image]

Comment: Try to figure out which process is occupying this file, and terminate it. For example you can use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

Install Android Studio and install the android packages from there. The program takes care of a lot of the initialisation process when installing the Android SDk, platforms tools, and the emulator. It seems to do a better job at it than Visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

From the screenshot, the manager is being downloading the **SDK Platforms 29**, you should wait for other processes be finished. Then click the option of **Android Emulator** and **Apply Changes** to check whether it works.

[image]